# How to fail task if there are no artifacts

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a step in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to run a script that generates some artifacts. Under normal circumstances, the directory contains artifacts and they are are picked up as such by gitlab-ci. But, I'm trying to set things up so that the task fails if there are no artifacts. All I get now is a warning in the log telling me there are no artifacts. I want to treat this warning as an error and fail the task. Is there a way to do this?

I suppose I could just update my bash script to exit non-zero if the artifacts aren't present, but I'd like to do it in the gitlab task definition if possible.

```
rpm_build:
  stage: build
  script: ./scripts/build_rpms.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - my/RPMS/
    expire_in: 3 days
```

I've looked at the documentation on the artifacts section, but couldn't find anything.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#artifacts

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, this is still an open issue in GitLab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18921

Therefore you will have to resort to updating your script in a way that it returns a non-zero exit status.

Comment: 2022 and still this is an open issue... https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22711

Comment: Still an issue in 2023.